# Inverse Laplace computation Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, integral-transforms

I have a transfer function such as following, which I would like to find its inverse:

```
F=(a*s^2)/(b*s^3+c*s^2+d*s+e)
```

I have a numeric value for a b c d and e but I would like my final answer to be based on coefficients meaning something like a*exp(b*t)+.... I also know all of these coefficients are greater than 0. Is there anyway to do this by mathematica since I have tried this on Mathematica and I use the command `InverseLaplaceTransform(F,s,t)`

but I got very long expression involving a lot of Root such as a*Root(...), which I do not know how to remove them. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: `Root[p, k]` just represents the `k`-th root of the polynomial `p`. You can try using `ToRadicals[]`, but the expressions you'll get will likely be very unwieldy.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I believe you'll find the questions and answers that you post here better received if the code and code snippets you use follow *Mathematica's* syntax.  For instance if you paste `InverseLaplaceTransform (F, s, t)` into *Mathematica* and try to execute it, you'll get a syntax error.  Note that I indented your code for `F` by four spaces, which is how to properly format code.  Now it's more readable compare to what it was originally. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: You are almost there. `InverseLaplaceTransform[F, s, t] // ToRadicals // Simplify ` does the job. The result is an analytical expression. It is, however, a very long one, so that I cannot imagine that one can ever use it.